# Suggestion for a pattern involving bits using bit manipulation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I currently have a structure like this

```
struct foo
{
  UINT64 optionA = 0;
  UINT64 optionB = 0;
  UINT64 optionC = 0;
}
```

I am attempting to write a function for comparing two objects of `foo` based on `optionA` , `optionB` and `optionC`. Essentially what I would like the function to do is check if `optionA` is the same in both if no then return the lowest object back. If the `optionA` in both objects are the same then it will check `optionB` in both objects and would return the lowest one. If `optionB` are the same in both then it will look at `optionC` and return the lowest.

I am thinking that this could be accomplished by assigning a UINT64 no to each object.
Then assigning bits based on priority to that no and then comparing each and returning back the lesser one. I am not sure how to go about that approach any suggestions to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: With only three values you could hard code your priorities.  Are you saying that you want the priorities to be dynamic?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah yes the values in OptionA, OptionB and OptionC can be anything. They are dynamic And these options determine the priority. OptionA has the first most priority, then B and then C

Comment: So what about `foo compare(foo x, foo y) { if (x.optionA != y.optionA) return x.optionA < y.optionA ? x : y; else if (x.optionB != y.optionB) return x.optionB < y.optionB ? x : y; else if (x.optionC != y.optionC) return x.optionC < y.optionC ? x : y; else return x; /* if they are exactly the same */ }`

Comment: This is a [_lexicographic comparison_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) and you likely want an array of options rather than named options.

Comment: If you really wanted to do it with a variable that holds bits for each object's members to say whether or not it is larger or smaller than the other object's members  then this might do what you want: https://onlinegdb.com/MRtzS0S2b

Comment: You want to do lexicographical comparison. This is easy with the new spaceship operator. You have to define the option members in the right priority order and declare a defaulted spaceship operator. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/simplify-your-code-with-rocket-science-c20s-spaceship-operator/ at chapter more complex types. Afterwords `std::min` will return the smaller object (include `algorithm`).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah that is exactly what I was looking for can you tell me why you used an `unsigned char` instead of an `int` ? an int can hold multiple digits after shifting. I am not sure how a char helps here. Can you explain that. I simply replaced the unsigned char of status with `int`

Comment: It doesn't matter what size integer you use because you only need three bits.  So I used the smallest integer that would hold those three bits.  I wasn't suggesting you had to use it - any integer type is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be simpler and more readable to just have a comparison function that directly compares the data members in the right order, but if having bit masks that store which data members are bigger is helpful for some other reason then here is how I would do it:

```
foo compare(foo x, foo y)
{
    // needs to hold status for 3 data members (one bit each)
    int x_status = 0, y_status = 0;

    // each bit is 1 if this member is bigger, 0 if smaller
    x_status |= (x.optionC > y.optionC)<<0;
    x_status |= (x.optionB > y.optionB)<<1;
    x_status |= (x.optionA > y.optionA)<<2;

    // each bit is 1 if this member is bigger, 0 if smaller
    y_status |= (x.optionC < y.optionC)<<0;
    y_status |= (x.optionB < y.optionB)<<1;
    y_status |= (x.optionA < y.optionA)<<2;

    // so now we can compare the values
    // if all the data members were bigger the value will be 7 (0b111)
    // if all the data members were smaller the value will be 0 (0b000)
    if (x_status < y_status) return x; else return y;
}
```

Try it online here: https://onlinegdb.com/XpdOSFLFa

Answer (score 2):

With C++20, [default](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) [`operator <=>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Three-way_comparison) and `operator ==` would do the job.

```
struct foo
{
  UINT64 optionA = 0;
  UINT64 optionB = 0;
  UINT64 optionC = 0;

  auto operator <=>(const foo&) const = default;
  bool operator ==(const foo&) const = default;
};
```

else, `std::tuple` might help:

```
bool operator ==(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)
{
   return std::tie(lhs.optionA, lhs.optionB, lhs.optionC)
       == std::tie(rhs.optionA, rhs.optionB, rhs.optionC);
}

bool operator <(const foo& lhs, const foo& rhs)
{
   return std::tie(lhs.optionA, lhs.optionB, lhs.optionC)
        < std::tie(rhs.optionA, rhs.optionB, rhs.optionC);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is currently missing an operator that checks for equallity.

Example:

```
constexpr bool operator==(const foo& a, const foo& b) {
    return
        a.optionA == b.optionA &&
        a.optionB == b.optionB &&
        a.optionC == b.optionC;
}
```

With that, the below would compile (meaningfully):

```
using UINT64 = /* unsigned long long */; // usually

struct foo {
    UINT64 optionA = 0;
    UINT64 optionB = 0;
    UINT64 optionC = 0;
};

constexpr bool operator==(const foo& a, const foo& b) {
    return
        a.optionA == b.optionA &&
        a.optionB == b.optionB &&
        a.optionC == b.optionC;
}

int main() {
    constexpr foo a, b;
    static_assert(a == b);
}
```